# Setting a property value of javascript object

Tags: javascript

I could not set new value to my javascript object which includes some `ko.observables`.
I am getting the value like this:

```
     var args= {"argBO":{"StateId":0,"StateName":"beijing","ShortName":"bij","IsActive":true,"CountryId":28,"errors":[],"CountryName":"China"}}
```

and I am trying to assign  a new StateName as follows:

```
 1. ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO[StateName] = 'Assasw';
 2. ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName = 'Assasw'; 
 3. ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO.StateName('Assasw');
```

It is not working! Can you tell me where the problem is and how can i fix it?

**UPDATE:**

```
  var stateModel = {
            StateId: ko.observable(0),
            StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
            ShortName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
            IsActive: ko.observable(true),
            CountryId: ko.observable().extend({ required: true })

        }

  var args = JSON.stringify({ argBO: jQuery.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(stateModel)) });
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you believe that `args.argBO` has the correct structure to be added to that way?

Comment: Why do you think you have to call `parseJson`? This is already an object.

Comment: Drop the `parseJSON()` and pick option 2, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jXLrn/

Comment: not showing error but value of StateName is not changing to my new value

Comment: Then the larger problem is coming from where you are changing  `args` and where you are reading it.  This will require more code to figure out

Comment: as i wrote in question i am getting the args values from  knock out observable's model

Comment: @Jason Sperske u can see where args coming from in my update!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, that assigning the new value everytime to the parsed object is not saving the value! You need to:

- parse your object
- change the value
- save current object state (or overwrite existing object)

You can access and change the value of the object after the parse using the one of the many possible notations in JavaScript

`object["propertyName"] = value`:

This code changes the property value to `New York`:

```
var argbo = ko.utils.parseJson(args).argBO;
argbo["StateName"] = "New York";
alert(argbo["StateName"]);
```